# How to print request NSMutableURLRequest in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

tl;dr; 
I want to print generated (by [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)) request (or at least request body) using Swift

I receive `NSMutableURLRequest` object.
I have tried:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON{ request, response, JSON, error in
        println(request)
```

But I receive (debugger output):

```
(lldb) p println(request)
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7faac257f520> { URL: http://apphb.com/api/x }
```

Maybe `description`?

```
(lldb) p println(request.description)
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7faac257f520> { URL: http://apphb.com/api/x}
```

`HTTPBody`? ( `...` below == output shortened manually be me )

```
(lldb) p println(request.HTTPBody!)
<416e7377 65727325 ... 38323833>
```

Ecoding - not so bad but not formatted

```
(lldb) p println(NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
Answers%5B%5D%5BAnswerId%5D=65&An...
```

But I want to get full request and body as JSON (using SwiftyJSON?) - how to achieve it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Alamofire, but I'll bet response and JSON are in the `response` and `JSON` variables, not in `request`. What does `println(response)` print?

Comment: Mistake in last line - I need request (response and response JSON are printed fine)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding getting request HTTPBody I was missing `encoding: .JSON` in `Alamofire.request` so after change to:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON{ request, response, JSON, error in

    println(NSString(data: request.HTTPBody!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

I get:

```
{"Answers":[{"AnswerId" ...
```

or to get data in pretty printed:

```
println(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(request.HTTPBody!,options:nil, error:nil)!)
```

What gives

```
{
Answers =     (
            {
        AnswerId = 66;
        QuestionId = 22;
    },
            {
        AnswerId = ...
```